# ESAPI url query parameter indirection using AccessReferenceMap & cobrowsing issues

Tags: security, url, esapi

We use ESAPI to secure query string parameters. The indirect reference created keeps changing and that is causing issues when we try sharing the URL/ implement co-browsing. Is there a way to create indirect reference that is consistent for a period of time - e.g. 1 hr or 1 day. This way sharing of URL/ co-browsing would work. I guess, it will also introduce a level of insecurity that the indirect reference/ AccessReferenceMap was supposed to address.

Any other suggestions/ ideas on how to handle this situation are welcome - we need to secure querystring parameters and yet allow for sharing of URL/ co-browsing between authenticated users

Comment: Could you provide some sample inputs and maybe a little code to reproduce the behavior so we can give you an answer?

Comment: I am not sure if this will be good enough CaseID: 110 results in encoded parameter caseId=uABpeg&. This encoded value keeps changing . The ESAPI.properties file has the following Encryptor.EncryptionAlgorithm=AES
Encryptor.CipherTransformation=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Comment: If you could write a little PoC or unit test that can capture the behavior you describe, you can post that.  Show the code that is generating/reading the reference... it sounds like you're encrypting query parameters, and that's generally a bad idea.